Why, when Klal Yisroel were scared to go into Eretz Yisroel after the meraglim returned, did this cause a קָרְבָּן and גָּלוּת until moshiach comes?
We know that Klal Yisroel were afraid to go into Eretz Yisroel, because they felt that they had committed too many sins, and lost their Divine protection, which appears to be a legitimate reason to be afraid.
Therefore the question is posed, why did this cause a korban for all future generations, and a galus until moshiach comes?

Welcome to Mi Yodeya. As this site works differently to other sites, I hope you've had a chance to see the site tour, and help center. Note specifically that we have a policy on jargon, please take a look, and edit accordingly.

Welcome to Mi Yodeya, great question.

See this answer which explains why it is considered a sin to say "I am worried Hashem will retract His promises to me, because I might sin/have sinned".
See this Rabbenu Bachaya for why doing so regarding Eretz Yisrael was considered such a terrible violation of this principle.

To summarise: the whole point of choosing the Jewish people was for Hashem to take them to Eretz Yisrael and build a "bayit ne'eman". This was the vision of our forefathers and Hashem's purpose. Therefore, refusal to proceed is considered one of the worst sins we ever did, and is indeed practically unforgivable, as there is no alternative plan. Therefore the only solution was for Hashem to wipe us out, but Moshe prayed for the maximum amount of forgiveness possible. This was that Hashem spread out his anger over many generations, so that each generation only received a managable amount, and we went into גָּלוּת until all of the sin is atoned for.
As for the point you made that the Jews were only afraid for seemingly legitimate reasons, i.e. they were worried that they would die not because Hashem can't protect them, but because Hashem would refuse to protect them because of their sins, this is considered a sin. Even Yaacov Avinu did this and it was counted as a sin. The basic explanation is, a true marriage is not conditional. If a wife thinks that her husband only loves her conditionally, and every day is watching to see if she will sin, and is constantly ready to back out of the relationship the moment she does, then surely the husband will be upset with her for this. He promised to be with her unconditionally, and she doubts it? That's a breach of trust, bitachon, in a relationship.
